# What are the pro's and cons between the two coveralls python packages?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, code-coverage, travis-ci, coveralls

Coveralls.io has two pip plugins referenced from its docs at https://coveralls.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201342869-Python

E.g. https://github.com/z4r/python-coveralls and https://github.com/coagulant/coveralls-python

I've seen docs and projects interchangeably using either or. But they have different config arguments and such.

My use-case is for travis-ci in a NON django environment, but I'd welcome a pro's/con's list for other environments as well incase I ever need it.

I couldn't find any explanation for why there are two options here.